# Searchdomains systemd-resolve with wireguard

Tags: linux, networking, dns, arch-linux, resolv.conf

Im using a WG tunnel at home to connect to my management network from my Arch linux installation, lets say its called mgmt.local, and my home network is called home.local

if i ping vcenter.home.local it works
if i ping vcenter.mgmt.local it doesnt work

```
ping: vcenter.mgmt.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

nslookup:

```
nslookup vcenter.home.local                                                                                           
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   vcenter.khome.lo
```

cal
Address: 10.xx.xx.10

i have both forward lookup zones in my MS AD controllers and it all works when running windows.

So i guess i somehow have to set searchdomains for the WG interface? the strange thing it was all working yesterday, all i have done since then is installed kvm/qemu and upgraded the system

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
asswd: files systemd
group: files [SUCCESS=merge] systemd
shadow: files systemd
gshadow: files systemd

publickey: files

#hosts: mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns
hosts: mymachines resolve files myhostname dns

networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to solve it by editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
and there change:

```
DNS=mydnsserver
Domains=local
```